# AMD GPU 470 issues on Ubuntu 18.04 [Error hw_init of IP block][*ERROR* ring kiq_2.1.0 test failed (-110)]

Tags: hardware

So i recently purchased 5 amd sapphire 470 4gb mining edition cards. When everything is up and running, 3 of the cards work perfectly fine. But two get the same error on post and when I run dmesg. the computer posts and runs fine when I have one of the good working card in the system. But hangs on boot with the errors when I do not. The below examples are when I have 2 good cards plugged in and when I have one bad card plugged in. I noticed that the bad cards do not show to have any evidence of a kernel driver in use, but I do not know how to remedy this situation. To give further information, all of the bios switches for all five cards are on the same settings so I am kinda running out of ideas on how to fix this and am not seeing much with someone with the same exact error online, especially someone running ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am getting quite lost.

[ 3.077526] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring kiq_2.1.0 test failed (-110)

[ 3.078372] [drm:amdgpu_device_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* hw_init of IP block <gfx_v8_0> failed -110

**For three working and one not working card**

**here is the lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cit -d " " -f 1 | xargs -i lspci -v -s {}**

02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev cf) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/580]

Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42

Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]

Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]

I/O ports at e000 [size=256]

Memory at f7c00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]

Expansion ROM at f7c40000 [disabled] [size=128K]

Capabilities:

Kernel driver in use: amdgpu

Kernel modules: amdgpu

05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev cf) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/580]

Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 43

Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]

Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]

I/O ports at c000 [size=256]

Memory at f7900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]

Expansion ROM at f7940000 [disabled] [size=128K]

Capabilities:

Kernel modules: amdgpu

06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev cf) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/580]

Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44

Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]

Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]

I/O ports at b000 [size=256]

Memory at f7800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]

Expansion ROM at f7840000 [disabled] [size=128K]

Capabilities:

Kernel driver in use: amdgpu

Kernel modules: amdgpu

**When I run dmesg | grep -i drm I can see the error again.**

[ 1.324106] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.

[ 1.324107] [drm] amdgpu version: 5.9.10.20.50

[ 1.324108] [drm] OS DRM version: 5.4.0

[ 1.325551] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (POLARIS10 0x1002:0x67DF 0x174B:0x353E 0xCF).

[ 1.325563] [drm] register mmio base: 0xF7C00000

[ 1.325563] [drm] register mmio size: 262144

[ 1.325565] [drm] PCIE atomic ops is not supported

[ 1.325571] [drm] add ip block number 0 <vi_common>

[ 1.325571] [drm] add ip block number 1 <gmc_v8_0>

[ 1.325572] [drm] add ip block number 2 <tonga_ih>

[ 1.325572] [drm] add ip block number 3 <gfx_v8_0>

[ 1.325573] [drm] add ip block number 4 <sdma_v3_0>

[ 1.325573] [drm] add ip block number 5

[ 1.325574] [drm] add ip block number 6

[ 1.325574] [drm] add ip block number 7 <uvd_v6_0>

[ 1.325575] [drm] add ip block number 8 <vce_v3_0>

[ 1.567648] [drm] UVD is enabled in VM mode

[ 1.567649] [drm] UVD ENC is enabled in VM mode

[ 1.567652] [drm] VCE enabled in VM mode

[ 1.567667] [drm] GPU posting now...

[ 1.684172] [drm] vm size is 64 GB, 2 levels, block size is 10-bit, fragment size is 9-bit

[ 1.684209] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=4096M, BAR=256M

[ 1.684210] [drm] RAM width 256bits GDDR5

[ 1.684352] [drm] amdgpu: 4096M of VRAM memory ready

[ 1.684354] [drm] amdgpu: 4096M of GTT memory ready.

[ 1.684355] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 65536, num gpu pages 65536

[ 1.684978] [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400000000).

[ 1.685073] [drm] Chained IB support enabled!

[ 1.686446] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 1.130 Family ID: 16

[ 1.694356] [drm] Found VCE firmware Version: 53.26 Binary ID: 3

[ 2.008620] [drm] Display Core initialized with v3.2.114!

[ 2.009939] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).

[ 2.009940] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.

[ 2.036227] [drm] UVD and UVD ENC initialized successfully.

[ 2.136175] [drm] VCE initialized successfully.

[ 2.136429] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes

[ 2.396362] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.40.0 20150101 for 0000:02:00.0 on minor 0

[ 2.396554] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (POLARIS10 0x1002:0x67DF 0x174B:0x353E 0xCF).

[ 2.396564] [drm] register mmio base: 0xF7900000

[ 2.396565] [drm] register mmio size: 262144

[ 2.396567] [drm] PCIE atomic ops is not supported

[ 2.396572] [drm] add ip block number 0 <vi_common>

[ 2.396573] [drm] add ip block number 1 <gmc_v8_0>

[ 2.396573] [drm] add ip block number 2 <tonga_ih>

[ 2.396574] [drm] add ip block number 3 <gfx_v8_0>

[ 2.396574] [drm] add ip block number 4 <sdma_v3_0>

[ 2.396574] [drm] add ip block number 5

[ 2.396575] [drm] add ip block number 6

[ 2.396575] [drm] add ip block number 7 <uvd_v6_0>

[ 2.396576] [drm] add ip block number 8 <vce_v3_0>

[ 2.636746] [drm] UVD is enabled in VM mode

[ 2.636746] [drm] UVD ENC is enabled in VM mode

[ 2.636750] [drm] VCE enabled in VM mode

[ 2.636766] [drm] GPU posting now...

[ 2.752686] [drm] vm size is 64 GB, 2 levels, block size is 10-bit, fragment size is 9-bit

[ 2.752707] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=4096M, BAR=256M

[ 2.752708] [drm] RAM width 256bits GDDR5

[ 2.752721] [drm] amdgpu: 4096M of VRAM memory ready

[ 2.752723] [drm] amdgpu: 4096M of GTT memory ready.

[ 2.752724] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 65536, num gpu pages 65536

[ 2.753193] [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400000000).

[ 2.753254] [drm] Chained IB support enabled!

[ 2.754984] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 1.130 Family ID: 16

[ 2.762962] [drm] Found VCE firmware Version: 53.26 Binary ID: 3

[ 3.077526] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring kiq_2.1.0 test failed (-110)

[ 3.078372] [drm:amdgpu_device_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* hw_init of IP block <gfx_v8_0> failed -110

[ 3.080205] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (POLARIS10 0x1002:0x67DF 0x174B:0x353E 0xCF).

[ 3.080212] [drm] register mmio base: 0xF7800000

[ 3.080213] [drm] register mmio size: 262144

[ 3.080214] [drm] PCIE atomic ops is not supported

[ 3.080220] [drm] add ip block number 0 <vi_common>

[ 3.080220] [drm] add ip block number 1 <gmc_v8_0>

[ 3.080220] [drm] add ip block number 2 <tonga_ih>

[ 3.080221] [drm] add ip block number 3 <gfx_v8_0>

[ 3.080221] [drm] add ip block number 4 <sdma_v3_0>

[ 3.080221] [drm] add ip block number 5

[ 3.080222] [drm] add ip block number 6

[ 3.080222] [drm] add ip block number 7 <uvd_v6_0>

[ 3.080223] [drm] add ip block number 8 <vce_v3_0>

[ 3.319800] [drm] UVD is enabled in VM mode

[ 3.319800] [drm] UVD ENC is enabled in VM mode

[ 3.319804] [drm] VCE enabled in VM mode

[ 3.319823] [drm] GPU posting now...

[ 3.436153] [drm] vm size is 64 GB, 2 levels, block size is 10-bit, fragment size is 9-bit

[ 3.436176] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=4096M, BAR=256M

[ 3.436176] [drm] RAM width 256bits GDDR5

[ 3.436197] [drm] amdgpu: 4096M of VRAM memory ready

[ 3.436199] [drm] amdgpu: 4096M of GTT memory ready.

[ 3.436201] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 65536, num gpu pages 65536

[ 3.436715] [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400000000).

[ 3.436775] [drm] Chained IB support enabled!

[ 3.437609] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 1.130 Family ID: 16

[ 3.445422] [drm] Found VCE firmware Version: 53.26 Binary ID: 3

[ 3.759443] [drm] Display Core initialized with v3.2.114!

[ 3.760366] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).

[ 3.760367] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.

[ 3.787052] [drm] UVD and UVD ENC initialized successfully.

[ 3.887005] [drm] VCE initialized successfully.

[ 3.887272] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes

[ 4.146985] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.40.0 20150101 for 0000:06:00.0 on minor 1

[ 5.474470] fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA

[ 5.475612] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).

[ 5.475612] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.

[ 5.491278] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20190822 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 2

[ 5.534406] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device

[ 5.580029] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device

Comment: could you solve this error? I've got the same